runtime comparison of 2 approaches of the Min Stack leetcode problem
Problem:
Implement a stack of integers with an extra method, getMin, which should have O(1) time complexity.
I solved this problem using 2 stacks, one to save the minimum value, and the other to do everything else.
class MinStack {
public:
    stack<int> st;
    stack<int> mins;

    MinStack() {}
    
    void push(int val) {
        st.push(val);
        if (mins.empty() || mins.top() >= val)
            mins.push(val);
    }
    
    void pop() {
        if (mins.top() == st.top())
            mins.pop();
        st.pop();
    }
    
    int top() {
        return st.top();
    }
    
    int getMin() {
        return mins.top();
    }
};

I also used a minheap in another solution, which I believe should run slower than the approach above (since it has runtime of O(log n)).
class MinHeap {
private:
    vector<int> heap;

    void heapifyUp(int index) {
        while (index > 0) {
            int parentIndex = (index - 1) / 2;

            if (heap[index] >= heap[parentIndex]) {
                break;
            }

            swap(heap[index], heap[parentIndex]);
            index = parentIndex;
        }
    }

    void heapifyDown(int index) {
        int leftChild, rightChild, smallestChild;

        while (true) {
            leftChild = 2 * index + 1;
            rightChild = 2 * index + 2;
            smallestChild = index;

            if (leftChild < heap.size() && heap[leftChild] < heap[smallestChild]) {
                smallestChild = leftChild;
            }

            if (rightChild < heap.size() && heap[rightChild] < heap[smallestChild]) {
                smallestChild = rightChild;
            }

            if (smallestChild == index) {
                break;
            }

            swap(heap[index], heap[smallestChild]);
            index = smallestChild;
        }
    }

    int find(int value) const {
        for (int i = 0; i < heap.size(); ++i) {
            if (heap[i] == value) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

public:
    void insert(int value) {
        heap.push_back(value);
        heapifyUp(heap.size() - 1);
    }

    int extractMin() {
        int minValue = heap[0];
        heap[0] = heap.back();
        heap.pop_back();
        heapifyDown(0);

        return minValue;
    }

    int getMin() const {
        return heap[0];
    }

    void deleteValue(int value) {
        int index = find(value);

        if (index == -1) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Value not found in the heap");
        }

        // Replace the element to be deleted with the last element
        heap[index] = heap.back();
        heap.pop_back();

        // Rebalance the heap
        if (index < heap.size()) {
            heapifyDown(index);
            heapifyUp(index);
        }
    }

    bool isEmpty() const {
        return heap.empty();
    }
};

class MinStack {
public:
    MinHeap mh;
    stack<int> st;
    MinStack() { }
    
    void push(int val) {
        st.push(val);
        mh.insert(val);
    }
    
    void pop() {
        mh.deleteValue(st.top());
        st.pop();
    }
    
    int top() {
        return st.top();
    }
    
    int getMin() {
        return mh.getMin();
    }
};

But to my surprise, the second approach was faster than the first one.
I know my question may seem dumb but I really don't understand the reason. Is it because of the hardware? or maybe some kind of optimization?
I submitted the same code several times to see if it changes, but the first code didn't get better runtime than the other one.

Time complexity is not a measure of actual execution time.
